# Need help in converting my PHP & MySQL script from mysql to mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql

My script was working before but when I changed all the mysql tags to mysqli everything stopped working. Can some please help me make the script work agian.

Here is the script.

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "sitename";

mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($db_name);

function tag_info() {

$page = "3";.
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT tags.tag, COUNT(questions_tags.tag_id) 'num' FROM questions_tags JOIN tags ON tags.id = questions_tags.tag_id WHERE questions_tags.users_questions_id = '$page' GROUP BY tags.tag ORDER BY num DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$arr[$row['tag']] = $row['num'];
}
ksort($arr);
return $arr;
}

function tag_cloud() {

$min_size = .8;
$max_size = 1.5;

$tags = tag_info();

$minimum_count = min(array_values($tags));
$maximum_count = max(array_values($tags));
$spread = $maximum_count - $minimum_count;

if($spread == 0) {
$spread = 1;
}

$cloud_html = '';
$cloud_tags = array();

foreach ($tags as $tag => $count) {
$size = $min_size + ($count - $minimum_count)
* ($max_size - $min_size) / $spread;
$cloud_tags[] = '<a style="font-size: '. $size . 'em'
. '" class="tag_cloud" href="http://www.example.com/tags/' . $tag .'/'
. '" title="\'' . $tag . '\' returned a count of ' . $count . '">'
. htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($tag)) . '</a>';
}
$cloud_html = join("\n", $cloud_tags) . "\n";
return $cloud_html;

}

?>

<div id="wrapper">
<?php print tag_cloud(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming you aren't getting any obvious error messages that you can fix. Throw a `die('Made it to here!');` into the script somewhere near the top and then progressively move it down. This can help if you don't know where something is breaking.

Answer (score 3):

Converting from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` is not **that** simple : you should take a quick look at the manual ;-)

For instance, you'll see that [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) is waiting for two parameters, in procedural style :

```
mixed mysqli_query  ( mysqli $link  , string $query  [, int $resultmode  ] )
```

Which means you have to pass the link identifier *(returned by [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php))* as a first parameter -- and the SQL query as the second one, and not the first one as you did.

The same stands for [mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php), btw :

```
bool mysqli_select_db  ( mysqli $link  , string $dbname  )
```

And maybe for other functions too : I didn't check the manual for every functions your are using.

Another one : when checking if the connection (call to [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php)) has been successfully established or not, you should not use [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), but the dedicated function [`mysqli_connect_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php).

And [`mysqli_error`], that you can get to determine if there was an error during the execution of a query, also takes the link identifier as a parameter.

As a sidenote : when reading the documentation for `mysqli_*`, note that this extension has two API :

- object oriented
- and procedural style

The functions using the procedural style often require more parameters *(especially, the link identifier)* than the methods when using OO-style...

Comment: @SlaPtHiS : I've edited my answer a couple of times to add some informations : basically, you need to check every call you make to each mysqli_* function -- and taking a look at the manual would really help you ;-)

Comment: I've been trying to fix the code for a while if the manual don't help look out for another question. I'll give it another try.

Comment: Have fun :-) And, as a sidenote : activating error_reporting and display_errors might help a bit ; you can add this at the beginning of your script, while developping ::: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors, 'On');

Comment: How come I never heard of this error reporting have any docs on it?

Comment: Well, the PHP manual ;-)  ;; http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting for instance